# Cannot add BinarySubTree

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-tree

It works well only if the node is attached to the left or right branch of the tree. But when it comes to attaching node to the sub tree, it turns out it's not successfully added. Here is the code:

```
class BinaryTree():
    class BinaryTreeNode():
        def __init__(self,leftchildnode,rightchildnode,item):
            self.leftchildnode = leftchildnode
            self.rightchildnode = rightchildnode
            self.item = item

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
    
    def setRoot(self,item):
        self.cur = self.BinaryTreeNode(None,None,item)
        self.root = self.cur

    def attachLeft(self,item):
        self.left = self.BinaryTreeNode(self.root.leftchildnode,None,item)
        self.root.leftchildnode = self.left

    def attachRight(self,item):
        self.right = self.BinaryTreeNode(None,self.root.rightchildnode,item)
        self.root.rightchildnode = self.right

    def attachLeftSub(self,Binarytree):
        global BinaryTree
        self.root.leftchildnode = BinaryTree
        BinaryTree = None
    
    def attachRightSub(self,Binarytree):
        global BinaryTree
        self.root.rightchildnode = BinaryTree
        BinaryTree = None

    def inorderdisplay(self):
        self.recursive_inorder_display(self.root)

    def recursive_inorder_display(self,BinaryTreeNode):
        if BinaryTreeNode != None:
            self.recursive_inorder_display(BinaryTreeNode.leftchildnode)
            print(BinaryTreeNode.item)
            self.recursive_inorder_display(BinaryTreeNode.rightchildnode)

tree = BinaryTree()
tree.setRoot("J")
tree1 = BinaryTree()
tree1.setRoot("D")
tree1.attachLeft("E")
tree1.attachRight("F")
tree2 = BinaryTree()
tree2.setRoot("G")
tree2.attachLeft("H")
tree2.attachRight("I")
tree.attachLeftSub(tree1)
tree.attachLeftSub(tree2)
tree.inorderdisplay()
```

It should have show all the item in order but the only item `I` get is `J`. Can you point out where's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def attachRightSub(self,Binarytree):
    global BinaryTree
    self.root.rightchildnode = BinaryTree
    BinaryTree = None
```

should be

```
def attachRightSub(self,BinaryTree):
    self.root.rightchildnode = BinaryTree.root
```

What you're doing instead is deleting your original `BinaryTree` class.

Comment: It turns out another error which is AttributeError: type object 'BinaryTree' has no attribute 'leftchildnode' at the inorder display part. Is my inorders code wrong?

Comment: Does it print any data before displaying the error?

Comment: Ah, I see, I made a mistake, you should be attaching `BinaryTree.root`; I'll correct the answer.

Comment: Hmm it says AttributeError: type object 'BinaryTree' has no attribute 'root'

Comment: Note the capitalization difference between your original function (`Binarytree`) and my answer (`BinaryTree`)

Comment: Even better, avoid reusing the name `BinaryTree`, call the parameter `subtree` or something, to prevent this kind of error.